# Bayesian networks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any example or toolbox in `MATLAB` Where I can apply bayesian networks?

I am solving a problem with 8 variables, But do not really how to begin, someone are dependent of some variables.

Comment: Take a look at the bnt toolbox: http://code.google.com/p/bnt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Bayes Net Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/) available via Google Code, complete with an introduction and examples. Hope this helps!