# Bayesian network implemented in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bayesian networks in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360640/bayesian-networks-in-matlab)

Is there a toolbox in Matlab which implement Bayesian Networks, or Bayesian Inference Problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used any myself, but a quick google search turned up the [Bayes Net Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/), which seems to be an open source 3rd party toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

[BNT](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/) has been around for years.